# Solving logarithmic equation $(e^x+e^{-x})/(e^x-e^{-x}) = 3$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the equation

$$(e^x+e^{-x})/(e^x-e^{-x}) = 3$$

I can solve it using a graph, but how would I go about solving it algebraically.

Comment: Let $e^x = u$, and rearrange to get a quadratic in $u$. We know that $u \neq 1$, and $u>0$. finally, $x = \log u_0$, where $u_0$ is an admissible solution.

Comment: @stochasticboy321: I have it down to $0 = 2(e^x-2e^{-x})$ but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: You can rearrange that to get $e^{2x} = 2 \implies x = \frac{1}{2} \ln 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved by simple manipulation:

$$ e^x + e^{-x} = 3e^x - 3e^{-x} $$
$$ -2e^x + 4e^{-x} = 0 $$
$$ e^x - 2e^{-x} = 0 $$
$$ e^{2x} = 2 $$
$$ \ln{e^{2x}} = \ln{2} $$
$$ 2x = \ln{2} $$
$$ x = \dfrac{\ln{2}}{2} $$

Comment: Could you expand on step 3 to 4?

Comment: Multiplication by $ e^x $ and moving the left over $ -2 $ to the right hand side. Recall that $ e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1 $.

Comment: Got it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the hyperbolic functions, you get
$$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac{2\cosh x}{2\sinh x}=\coth x=3$$
which means $x=\coth^{-1}3$ is a solution.

Otherwise, using stochasticboy's comment, you should be able to rewrite $\coth x$ as $1+\dfrac{2}{e^{2x}-1}$.

Comment: Haha.  Not that far yet:)

Answer (score 1):

Put $ e^x=t$ .

Then $\displaystyle \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}=\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}=3$ as $t>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

For $ t \neq 1 $$\Rightarrow t^2+1=3t^2-3 \Rightarrow  t^2=2 \Rightarrow e^{2x}=2$

$2x=ln(2)$.